# Omit default case in C++ switch case

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am trying to write a program that prints the 12 days of Christmas song.  Is there a way to not execute the default block of a switch?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string day[] = {"first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eith", "ninth", "tenth", "eleventh", "twelth"};

    for (int i = 1 ; i <= 12 ; i++) {
        string gift = "";

        switch (i) {
            case 12: gift += "twelve durmmers drumming, ";
            case 11: gift += "eleven pipers piping, ";
            case 10: gift += "ten lords a-leaping, ";
            case 9: gift += "nine ladies dancing, ";
            case 8: gift += "eight maids a-milking, ";
            case 7: gift += "seven swans a-swimming, ";
            case 6: gift += "six geese a-laying, ";
            case 5: gift += "five golden rings, ";
            case 4: gift += "four calling birds, ";
            case 3: gift += "three french hens, ";
            case 2: gift += "two turtle doves ";
            case 1:
                if(i > 1) {
                    gift += "and ";
                }
                gift += "a partrige in a pear tree";
            **default: gift = "a logic error";/// SHOULD NEVER EXECUTE**
        }

        cout << "On the " << day[i - 1] << " day of Chirstmas my true love gave to me " << gift << "." << endl;
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

The output prints this instead of the song:

On the first day of Chirstmas my true love gave to me a logic error.
    On the second day of Chirstmas my true love gave to me a logic error.
    On the third day of Chirstmas my true love gave to me a logic error.
    On the fourth day of Chirstmas my true love gave to me a logic error.
    On the fifth day of Chirstmas my true love gave to me a logic error.
    On the sixth day of Chirstmas my true love gave to me a logic error.
    On the seventh day of Chirstmas my true love gave to me a logic error. On the eigth day of Chirstmas my true love gave to me a logic error.
 On the ninth day of Chirstmas my true love gave to me a logic error.
 On the tenth day of Chirstmas my true love gave to me a logic    error.
 On the eleventh day of Chirstmas my true love gave to me a    logic error.
 On the twelth day of Chirstmas my true love gave to me a    logic error.
 Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Forgot about the `break` statement in `switch`es?

Comment: Just not have a default case, or do nothing in the default case.

Comment: The Twelve Days of [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting the `break` statement.  If there is no `break` statement, the logic will just flow into the next `case`, as it was doing with all of the other `cases` (12, 11, 10, etc.).

```
 case 2: gift += "two turtle doves ";
 case 1:
    if(i > 1) 
      gift += "and ";
    gift += "a partrige in a pear tree";
 break;  // <-- Missing

 default: gift = "a logic error";
```